# Removing multiple rows of a dataframe with with same column value when bad data is found in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe, "tracks", that I'm filtering for erroneous altitude information.
When the altitude is below a certain criteria, I want to throw out all rows that start with the same track_key. In the example, N123P, on track_key 4xuut, has an erroneous altitude, so I want to  remove ALL rows that start with "4xuut", but NOT the rows below them that have the same call sign.

| track_key | callsign | aircraft_type | speed | altitude |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4xuut | N123P | C550 | 300 | -1 |
| 4xuut | N123P | C550 | 297 | 15 |
| 4yt06 | N123P | C550 | 305 | 1022 |
| 4yt06 | N123P | C550 | 301 | 1028 |
| 4xx21 | N348U | GALX | 350 | 1025 |

I've tried this:
`tracks = tracks[tracks.track_key != tracks.loc[tracks['altitude'].astype('float') <= field_elev, 'track_key'].iloc[0]]`, but it only seems to work on the first match (there can be several), or, if there are no matches, I get an "out-of-bounds" error.

Comment: Helps is you show what you want the output to look like.

Comment: The output would be the same datafrme, with the first two rows removed, in this case. There could be a thousand such rows in the real data,

Comment: Try solution below, that should do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you see the error, `out of bounds` is because there is no value to access with an index 0 if there is no erroneous altitude value.

To solve the issue, I used `if` condition, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

tracks = pd.DataFrame({
    'track_key': ['4xuut', '4xuut', '4yt06', '4yt06', '4xx21'],
    'callsign': ['N123P', 'N123P', 'N123P', 'N123P', 'N348U'],
    'aircraft_type': ['C550', 'C550', 'C550', 'C550', 'GALX'],
    'speed': [300, 297, 305, 301, 350],
    'altitude': [-1, 15, 1022, 1028, 1025],
})
#  track_key callsign aircraft_type  speed  altitude
#0     4xuut    N123P          C550    300        -1
#1     4xuut    N123P          C550    297        15
#2     4yt06    N123P          C550    305      1022
#3     4yt06    N123P          C550    301      1028
#4     4xx21    N348U          GALX    350      1025

erroneous = -1

key_to_delete = tracks[tracks['altitude'] == erroneous]['track_key'].values
if len(key_to_delete) > 0:
    tracks = tracks[~tracks['track_key'].str.startswith(key_to_delete[0])]

print(tracks)
#  track_key callsign aircraft_type  speed  altitude
#2     4yt06    N123P          C550    305      1022
#3     4yt06    N123P          C550    301      1028
#4     4xx21    N348U          GALX    350      1025
```

Comment: Sangkuen, thanks for the explanation on the out-of-bounds error. Makes sense, now.

Comment: This method actually worked a bit better. Thanks, again!

Comment: @atc_ceedee happy to help u :)

Comment: @atc_ceedee If this helped solve your problem, pls mark this answer as accepted, so that this can help other users know this question is solved by this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
tracks[tracks.groupby('track_key').transform('min')['altitude']>0]
```

output

```
    track_key   callsign    aircraft_type   speed   altitude
2   4yt06       N123P       C550            305     1022
3   4yt06       N123P       C550            301     1028
4   4xx21       N348U       GALX            350     1025
```

Thanks to @bkeesey for this solution.

Comment: Cam, that did it! Much simpler, as well. I swapped out the ">0" for "<field_elev", in my case. Some of my aircraft had ADS-B altitudes that were below the field elevation.

Comment: Yes transform is nice, see docs here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html